# join of two lists in c#

Tags: c#, linq

```
public class Co
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public List<string> Cards { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<Co> coll = new List<Co>();
        Co c1 = new Co();
        c1.Id = 1;
        c1.Title = "A";
        coll.Add(c1);
        Co c2 = new Co();
        c2.Id = 2;
        c2.Title = "B";
        coll.Add(c2);
        List<KeyValuePair<int, int>> list = new List<KeyValuePair<int, int>>();
        list.Add(new KeyValuePair<int, int>(1, 2));
        list.Add(new KeyValuePair<int, int>(1, 3));
        list.Add(new KeyValuePair<int, int>(1, 1));
        list.Add(new KeyValuePair<int, int>(2, 1));

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

I want to assign Cards property for all the objects in `coll` with comma separated values of value in `list`  by comparing the id from object in `coll` with key from `list`

Output: for first object c.Cards ="2,3,1"
        for second object c.cards= "1"

I'm able to do it with foreach loops. Can anyone tell me the solution with linq?

Comment: Linq = Language-Integrated **Query**, Trying to do everything with Linq is not necessary, and the resultant code isn't more readable. See for ex, Julián's answer.

Comment: You'll benefit more from auto properties

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, note that your sample data is incorrect because you use the same `c` object twice. It should be like:

```
List<Co> coll = new List<Co>();
Co c = new Co();
c.Id = 1;
c.Title = "A";
coll.Add(c);
c = new Co(); // HERE
c.Id = 2;
c.Title = "B";
coll.Add(c);
List<KeyValuePair<int, int>> list = new List<KeyValuePair<int, int>>();
list.Add(new KeyValuePair<int, int>(1, 2));
list.Add(new KeyValuePair<int, int>(1, 3));
list.Add(new KeyValuePair<int, int>(1, 1));
list.Add(new KeyValuePair<int, int>(2, 1));
```

Now, note that your `Cards` property is a `List<string>`, not a `string`, so I don't know what you mean by "comma separated values". If `Cards` were a string:

```
coll.ForEach(co => co.Cards = String.Join(",",
    list.Where(l => l.Key == co.Id)
        .Select(l => l.Value)));
```

With you current definition as `List<string>`:

```
coll.ForEach(co => co.Cards =
    list.Where(l => l.Key == co.Id)
        .Select(l => l.Value.ToString()).ToList()
);
```

Comment: it gives this compile time error 'Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<string>''

Comment: @user270014 check updated answer for both solutions and an error in your sample data