# C# Making a new list by combining two lists together

Tags: c#

So I am trying to find how to best make a list that will combine two lists of equal size of two different types together, in a way so that the  indexes will be the same. How can i do this?

```
var list = new List<KeyValuePair<List<Card>, List<Card>>>();
list.AddRange(new List<KeyValuePair<List<Card>,List<Card>>>(_listCards,cloneOf_listCards));
```

The code above has been my way of trying to get it to work where Card is a class with both Suit and Cardnumber. though my code doesn't do it i wish to make it a list with Images instead of `Card` for one list. I have already seen these and many other threads: [join of two lists in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15993519/join-of-two-lists-in-c-sharp)
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16465804/return-two-combined-listt

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the [`Enumerable.Zip`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267698%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) extension method.

For example:

```
_listCards.Zip(cloneOf_listCards, (cardA, cardB) => new KeyValuePair<Card, Card>(cardA, cardB));
```

Granted, this will give you a single `List<KeyValuePair<Card,Card>>` instead of a `KeyValuePair<List<Card>, List<Card>>`, but I'd argue that's a better design anyways.

At that point (if you so desire), you can probably just turn it into a `Dictionary<Card,Card>`:

```
var joined = _listCards.Zip(cloneOf_listCards, (cardA, cardB) => new KeyValuePair<Card, Card>(cardA, cardB));
var dictionary = joined.ToDictionary(kv => kv.Key, kv => kv.Value);
```

Note that if your lists are of different sizes, `Enumerable.Zip` will only join the elements up to the end of the shorter list and then stop.